# Quotes inside of my PHP variable (wordpress shortcode) aren't returned

Tags: php, wordpress, svg, shortcode

I have spent hours on this, and I can't seem to find a way to fix my problem so I thought that an outside look would really help.

I have programmed a WordPress shortcode to better manage lazy loaded pictures on my portfolio. I am using a placeholder [URL-encoded SVG](https://css-tricks.com/preventing-content-reflow-from-lazy-loaded-images/) to prevent content reflow.

The svg is stored in a variable and contains quotes. The SVG is returned with the rest of the shortcode. However, the quotes surrounding the xmlns element of the SVG aren't returned.

Here is my code:

```
function img_shortcode( $atts , $content = null ) {

    // Attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'caption' => 'no',
            'src' => '',
            'name' => 'media',
            'captionclass' => 'caption',
            'width' => '0',
            'height' => '0',
        ),
        $atts,
        'img'
    );

    $urlsvg = "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 ". $atts['width'] ." ". $atts['height'] ."'%3E%3C/svg%3E";

    if($atts['caption'] == 'yes')
    {
        return '<figure class="container"><img class="lozad" src="' . $urlsvg . '" data-src="' . $atts['src'] . '" alt="' . $atts['name'] . '" /><figcaption class="' . $atts['captionclass'] . '">'.$content.'</figcaption></figure>';
    }
    else{
        return '<img class="lozad" src="' . $urlsvg . '"  data-src="' . $atts['src'] . '" alt="' . $atts['name'] . '" />';
    }

}
add_shortcode( 'img', 'img_shortcode' );
```

And here is what is returned:

```
<figure class="container"><img class="lozad" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=http://www.w3.org/2000/svg viewBox='0 0 1300 1248'%3E%3C/svg%3E" data-src="linktotheimage" alt="alttextofimg"><figcaption class="caption">Caption text.</figcaption></figure>
```

I am by no means a php expert, in fact I am certain that I am missing something that will be most obvious to everyone else but I can't seem to be able to see what it is that prevents my quotes from being returned.

I have tried to replace single quotes with double quotes and the outcome was the same.

Thanks,

Comment: And what do you __expect__ in returned code? It's unclear to me.

Comment: I want the xmlns value to be encompassed by the quotes, like so:
`xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why your single quotes are not returned in your string for `xmlns='..'`, but then for `viewBox='..'` they are. Your code seems to be fine.

What you can try is something called [escaping](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php), where you use the backslash (`\`) to remove any special meaning a character has. So for example, in your code you can  write

`$urlsvg = "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" viewBox=\"0 0 ". $atts['width'] ." ". $atts['height'] ."\"%3E%3C/svg%3E";` which only uses double quotes.

**Edit:** what caused this problem was the so called 'HTML Minifier', that removed the `"` or `'` characters.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately the outcome is the same, xmlns's value double quotes are not returned. :(

Comment: Maybe some minifyer is enabled? See https://wordpress.org/support/topic/html-minify-removes-double-quotes-from-html/. Thats sll i can think of.

Comment: Thank you, the minifier did cause the issue! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use backslashes around your quotes:
Instead of

```
$urlsvg = "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 ". $atts['width'] ." ". $atts['height'] ."'%3E%3C/svg%3E";
```

Try

```
$urlsvg = "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\' viewBox='0 0 ". $atts['width'] ." ". $atts['height'] ."'%3E%3C/svg%3E";
```

The backslashes should hopefully escape any -problems.

Comment: Thank you. I had actually tried this before, and this is what the code returned:

`<img class="lozad" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\' viewBox='0 0 1300 1248'%3E%3C/svg%3E" data-src="imglink" alt="KeyArtHA">`